# webpack + typescript: "Property 'jwplayer' does not exist on type 'Window'" when using script-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am making a fairly rudimentary component that looks as follows so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'lib/jwplayer-7.7.4/jwplayer.js';

interface Props {
  src: string,
};

export default class ShiftPlayer extends React.Component<Props> {
  element: HTMLDivElement = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { src, ...props } = this.props;
    window.jwplayer(this.element).setup({
      file: src,
      ...props,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={(el) => {
          this.element = el;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

However, this consistently shows an error in my IDE (VSCode):

[image]

Since the library is loaded via `script-loader`, I can assume that it exists on the window object.

Why is this? How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript only knows about standard `window` properties by default, so you have to tell it about about any non-standard globals such as `jwplayer`. This should do it:

```
interface Window {
    jwplayer: any;
}


window.jwplayer(...)
```

This solution uses [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment the standard `Window` interface. If you need to use `jwplayer` in multiple places, consider extracting the augmented Window interface to a `.d.ts` file

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Typescript definitions for jwplayer:

```
npm i @types/jwplayer
```

and then just use

```
jwplayer(ele).setup(...)
```